# Is there a transaction browser for ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Is there a transactions/blocks browser/explorer for Ethererum? Just like [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/home) or [blockexplorer](https://blockexplorer.com/) for bitcoin. I'd like to search a transaction for a given address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

https://etherscan.io

Hope it helps.